# Extracting elements with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xpath, nokogiri

Was wondering if someone could help out with the following. I am using Nokogiri to scrape some data from http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/tables

I would like to get the league table info, so far ive got this

```
def get_league_table # Get me Premier League Table
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
  table = doc.css('.table-stats')
  teams = table.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.team')
  teams.each do |team|
  position = team.css('.position-number').text.strip
  League.create!(position: position)
  end
end
```

So i thought i would grab the .table-stats and then get each row in the table with a class of team, these rows contain all the info I need, like position number, played,team-name etc.

Once I'm in the tr.team I thought I could do a loop to grab the relevant info from the rows.

Its the xpath part I am stuck on (unless I'm approaching the whole thing wrong?), how to get to the tr.team class from .table-stats?

Could anyone offer any pointers please?

Thanks

Comment: as an output what you want?

Comment: I'm saving the attributes to a model, so just need to grab it as text..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a script I made to dynamically parse tables, I adapted it to your case:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/tables'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open url)
teams = doc.search('tbody tr.team')

keys = teams.first.search('td').map do |k|
  k['class'].gsub('-', '_').to_sym
end

hsh = teams.flat_map do |team|
  Hash[keys.zip(team.search('td').map(&:text))]
end

puts hsh
```

Comment: @nicoga wow thats real nice, thanks, so each rows data is saved to a hash, so i can pull out the attributes i want, ie position, by grabbing the key/value?

Comment: theres some code in here which im not to sure with what is happening. i need to grab each team-name for example and save to model

Comment: Could you tell me the meaning of `tbody tr.team`? where such technique written in the `nokogiri` doc? out of curiosity I am asking,please let me know.

Comment: I'm grabbing the keys from the css class of each td in the first row. Normally it would be nicer to take them from the header, but those are clearer. Examine `teams.first.serarch('td')`, the output is a bit chunky but you can refactor the code to get the info you need.

Comment: @RubyLovely That's pretty standard way to write selectors, search for each `td` with css class `team` inside a tag `tbody`.