# Grabbing values from Hash ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, nokogiri

bit lost now on this one. I am grabbing table data from http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/tables using nokogiri. I sort some help from SO as was unsure how to grab some of the data I wanted, I was kindly provided with an example of something that they would do which looks like so

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/tables'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open url)
teams = doc.search('tbody tr.team')

keys = teams.first.search('td').map do |k|
  k['class'].gsub('-', '_').to_sym
end

hsh = teams.flat_map do |team|
  Hash[keys.zip(team.search('td').map(&:text))]
end

puts hsh
```

Im a little unclear with some of this, I can see that the final output hsh gives this Hash for example

```
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 20", :team_name=>"Reading", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"4", :home_drawn=>"7", :home_lost=>"6", :home_for=>"23", :home_against=>"31", :away_won=>"1", :away_drawn=>"2", :away_lost=>"13", :away_for=>"13", :away_against=>"32", :goal_difference=>"-27", :points=>"24", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Reading's last match                "}

{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 19", :team_name=>"QPR", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"2", :home_drawn=>"8", :home_lost=>"6", :home_for=>"12", :home_against=>"23", :away_won=>"2", :away_drawn=>"4", :away_lost=>"11", :away_for=>"17", :away_against=>"31", :goal_difference=>"-25", :points=>"24", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nDraw\nLoss\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nDraw\nLoss", :status=>"\n                    Report of QPR's last match                "}
```

So my thinking is that to grab each :team_name i would go through a loop like i normally would

```
hsh.each do |k,v]
  v['team_name']
end
```

So this would give me the value of team_name for every hash? What Im trying to achieve is at [Extracting elements with Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112078/extracting-elements-with-nokogiri/16112974#16112974) but i would like to make sense of the provided solution and save each value to my model

Could anyone help clarify some understanding please

Thanks

Comment: There is only one hash in your example. What other team names do you want?

Comment: yes there are multiple hashes returned, all in same format, about 20 but didnt want to list them all

Comment: so what you want exactly?

Comment: I want to grab multiple attributes such as team_name and save them to the model, i can do it if someone could give me an example of grabbing just one for now, so i have chosen team_name as the example.

Comment: `"team_name"`, a string, is not the same as `:team_name`, a symbol (unless you're using a `HashMapWithIndifferentAccess` or similar class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really do anything useful, it only iterates over `hsh` but doesn't do anything because the value you want will be in `k`:

```
hsh.each do |k,v]
  v['team_name']
end
```

The problem is that`hsh` is really an array of hashes. Keeping the same name, `hsh`, but treating it like an array:

```
hsh.map{ |a| a[:team_name]}
```

returns:

```
[
    [ 0] "Man Utd",
    [ 1] "Man City",
    [ 2] "Chelsea",
    [ 3] "Arsenal",
    [ 4] "Tottenham",
    [ 5] "Everton",
    [ 6] "Liverpool",
    [ 7] "West Brom",
    [ 8] "Swansea",
    [ 9] "Fulham",
    [10] "West Ham",
    [11] "Southampton",
    [12] "Newcastle",
    [13] "Norwich",
    [14] "Sunderland",
    [15] "Stoke",
    [16] "Aston Villa",
    [17] "Wigan",
    [18] "QPR",
    [19] "Reading"
]
```

It might be a bit easier to visualize if we only look at the first two entries in `hsh` using `hsh[0,2]`:

```
[15] (pry) main: 0> hsh[0,2]
[
    [0] {
             :statistics => "",
               :position => "No movement 1",
              :team_name => "Man Utd",
                 :played => "33",
               :home_won => "14",
             :home_drawn => "0",
              :home_lost => "2",
               :home_for => "40",
           :home_against => "17",
               :away_won => "12",
             :away_drawn => "3",
              :away_lost => "2",
               :away_for => "35",
           :away_against => "18",
        :goal_difference => "40",
                 :points => "81",
          :last_10_games => "\n                                    Win\nWin\nWin\nWin\nWin\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nDraw",
                 :status => "\n                    Report of Man Utd's last match                "
    },
    [1] {
             :statistics => "",
               :position => "No movement 2",
              :team_name => "Man City",
                 :played => "32",
               :home_won => "12",
             :home_drawn => "3",
              :home_lost => "1",
               :home_for => "36",
           :home_against => "11",
               :away_won => "8",
             :away_drawn => "5",
              :away_lost => "3",
               :away_for => "22",
           :away_against => "16",
        :goal_difference => "31",
                 :points => "68",
          :last_10_games => "\n                                    Win\nDraw\nDraw\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nWin",
                 :status => "\n                    Report of Man City's last match                "
    }
]
```

---

> i dont completely understand how we got the returned hash

You got the array of hashes because:

```
  Hash[keys.zip(team.search('td').map(&:text))]
```

coerces an array of key/value pairs into a hash. You got an array of key/value pairs because `keys.zip(team.search('td').map(&:text))` interweaves `keys` and the results of `team.search('td').map(&:text)`.

---

> so to save each team name to the model, can i now iterate through a loop?

```
File.open('team_names.txt', 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts hsh.map{ |a| a[:team_name] }
end
```

It might look like `hsh.map{ |a| a[:team_name] }.map(&:to_s)` is needed, but `puts` will do a `to_s` on every element in the returned array automatically, auto-converting the symbols back to strings for you.

---

> if i want to map out say team_name and position, so i have to create seperate calls, ie a map on each value? I cant map out multiple values in same call can I?

This will create an array of arrays:

```
ary_of_arys = hsh.map{ |a| [ a[:team_name], a[:position] ] }
```

This will join all the inner arrays for each row, then print out the rows:

```
File.open('team_names.txt', 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts hsh.map{ |a| [ a[:team_name], a[:position] ].join(', ') }
end
```

Comment: so my understanding was almost there? though i dont completely understand how we got the returned hash

Comment: ah ha i get all the team names returned, will look into an array of hashes i think

Comment: so to save each team name to the model, can i now iterate through a loop?

Comment: @Richlewis yes dear you can... use `map` to get them into an array. The same I tried to tell you,atlast you got it.

Comment: thanks @TinMan lots of explanations in there :)

Comment: NP. These sort of manipulations can bend your mind. Programming can be very abstract and learning how to unravel each step so you can see it all linearly is the challenge. I think of it like plumbing or garden hoses, going from one thingie to another, each doing something to the contents. You'll get there... or your head will explode. :-)

Comment: well head has exploded tonight, a fresh look tomorrow will help some more, ill go through each step...slowly

Comment: sorry @TinMan, could i ask one more question, if i want to map out say team_name and position, so i have to create seperate calls, ie a map on each value? I cant map out multiple values in same call can I?

Comment: @TinMan apologies to ask again, just wanted to clarify something, when performing the join on the values, how do i ensure that position value goes to position row, team-name goes to team-name row in the model.. for example i done something similar to this........teams.each do |team|
  position = team.css('.position-number').text.strip
  League.create!(position: position)    so i assigned a variable to each attribute

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/tables'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open url)
teams = doc.search('tbody tr.team')

keys = teams.first.search('td').map do |k|
  k['class'].gsub('-', '_').to_sym
end

hsh = teams.flat_map do |team|
  Hash[keys.zip(team.search('td').map(&:text))]
end
hsh.each do |x|
    p x[:team_name]
end
```

*Output:*

```
"Man Utd"
"Man City"
"Chelsea"
"Arsenal"
"Tottenham"
"Everton"
"Liverpool"
"West Brom"
"Swansea"
"Fulham"
"West Ham"
"Southampton"
"Newcastle"
"Norwich"
"Sunderland"
"Stoke"
"Aston Villa"
"Wigan"
"QPR"
"Reading"
```

***EDIT:***

```
puts hsh

{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 1", :team_name=>"Man Utd", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"14", :home_drawn=>"0", :home_lost=>"2", :home_for=>"40", :home_against=>"17", :away_won=>"12", :away_drawn=>"3", :away_lost=>"2", :away_for=>"35", :away_against=>"18", :goal_difference=>"40", :points=>"81", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Win\nWin\nWin\nWin\nWin\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Man Utd's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 2", :team_name=>"Man City", :played=>"32", :home_won=>"12", :home_drawn=>"3", :home_lost=>"1", :home_for=>"36", :home_against=>"11", :away_won=>"8", :away_drawn=>"5", :away_lost=>"3", :away_for=>"22", :away_against=>"16", :goal_difference=>"31", :points=>"68", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Win\nDraw\nDraw\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nWin", :status=>"\n                    Report of Man City's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"Moving up 3", :team_name=>"Chelsea", :played=>"32", :home_won=>"10", :home_drawn=>"4", :home_lost=>"2", :home_for=>"35", :home_against=>"13", :away_won=>"8", :away_drawn=>"3", :away_lost=>"5", :away_for=>"29", :away_against=>"20", :goal_difference=>"31", :points=>"61", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Win\nDraw\nLoss\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nWin", :status=>"\n                    Report of Chelsea's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"Moving down 4", :team_name=>"Arsenal", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"10", :home_drawn=>"4", :home_lost=>"3", :home_for=>"42", :home_against=>"21", :away_won=>"7", :away_drawn=>"5", :away_lost=>"4", :away_for=>"22", :away_against=>"14", :goal_difference=>"29", :points=>"60", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nWin\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nWin\nWin\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Arsenal's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 5", :team_name=>"Tottenham", :played=>"32", :home_won=>"8", :home_drawn=>"5", :home_lost=>"3", :home_for=>"24", :home_against=>"17", :away_won=>"9", :away_drawn=>"2", :away_lost=>"5", :away_for=>"31", :away_against=>"23", :goal_difference=>"15", :points=>"58", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nDraw\nWin\nWin\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nWin\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Tottenham's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 6", :team_name=>"Everton", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"10", :home_drawn=>"6", :home_lost=>"1", :home_for=>"30", :home_against=>"17", :away_won=>"4", :away_drawn=>"8", :away_lost=>"4", :away_for=>"21", :away_against=>"20", :goal_difference=>"14", :points=>"56", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Win\nDraw\nLoss\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nWin\nDraw\nWin\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Everton's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 7", :team_name=>"Liverpool", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"8", :home_drawn=>"4", :home_lost=>"4", :home_for=>"30", :home_against=>"14", :away_won=>"5", :away_drawn=>"7", :away_lost=>"5", :away_for=>"29", :away_against=>"26", :goal_difference=>"19", :points=>"50", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nDraw\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nDraw\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Liverpool's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 8", :team_name=>"West Brom", :played=>"32", :home_won=>"9", :home_drawn=>"2", :home_lost=>"5", :home_for=>"24", :home_against=>"16", :away_won=>"4", :away_drawn=>"3", :away_lost=>"9", :away_for=>"18", :away_against=>"27", :goal_difference=>"-1", :points=>"44", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nLoss\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nDraw\nLoss\nLoss", :status=>"\n                    Report of West Brom's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 9", :team_name=>"Swansea", :played=>"32", :home_won=>"6", :home_drawn=>"6", :home_lost=>"4", :home_for=>"28", :home_against=>"23", :away_won=>"4", :away_drawn=>"5", :away_lost=>"7", :away_for=>"15", :away_against=>"19", :goal_difference=>"1", :points=>"41", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Win\nDraw\nLoss\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Swansea's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 10", :team_name=>"Fulham", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"7", :home_drawn=>"3", :home_lost=>"6", :home_for=>"25", :home_against=>"22", :away_won=>"3", :away_drawn=>"7", :away_lost=>"7", :away_for=>"19", :away_against=>"29", :goal_difference=>"-7", :points=>"40", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Win\nLoss\nDraw\nWin\nDraw\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nDraw\nLoss", :status=>"\n                    Report of Fulham's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"Moving up 11", :team_name=>"West Ham", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"7", :home_drawn=>"5", :home_lost=>"4", :home_for=>"28", :home_against=>"20", :away_won=>"3", :away_drawn=>"4", :away_lost=>"10", :away_for=>"10", :away_against=>"27", :goal_difference=>"-9", :points=>"39", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Loss\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nDraw\nDraw\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of West Ham's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"Moving down 12", :team_name=>"Southampton", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"6", :home_drawn=>"6", :home_lost=>"5", :home_for=>"25", :home_against=>"20", :away_won=>"3", :away_drawn=>"5", :away_lost=>"8", :away_for=>"22", :away_against=>"34", :goal_difference=>"-7", :points=>"38", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Loss\nDraw\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nDraw\nWin\nWin\nWin\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Southampton's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 13", :team_name=>"Newcastle", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"9", :home_drawn=>"1", :home_lost=>"7", :home_for=>"24", :home_against=>"24", :away_won=>"1", :away_drawn=>"5", :away_lost=>"10", :away_for=>"18", :away_against=>"35", :goal_difference=>"-17", :points=>"36", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Win\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nWin\nLoss", :status=>"\n                    Report of Newcastle's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 14", :team_name=>"Norwich", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"6", :home_drawn=>"7", :home_lost=>"3", :home_for=>"18", :home_against=>"17", :away_won=>"1", :away_drawn=>"7", :away_lost=>"9", :away_for=>"13", :away_against=>"35", :goal_difference=>"-21", :points=>"35", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nDraw\nDraw\nWin\nLoss\nDraw\nDraw\nLoss\nDraw\nLoss", :status=>"\n                    Report of Norwich's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 15", :team_name=>"Sunderland", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"4", :home_drawn=>"6", :home_lost=>"6", :home_for=>"17", :home_against=>"17", :away_won=>"4", :away_drawn=>"4", :away_lost=>"9", :away_for=>"20", :away_against=>"28", :goal_difference=>"-8", :points=>"34", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nDraw\nLoss\nDraw\nLoss\nLoss\nWin", :status=>"\n                    Report of Sunderland's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 16", :team_name=>"Stoke", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"6", :home_drawn=>"7", :home_lost=>"4", :home_for=>"19", :home_against=>"20", :away_won=>"1", :away_drawn=>"6", :away_lost=>"9", :away_for=>"9", :away_against=>"21", :goal_difference=>"-13", :points=>"34", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nLoss\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nDraw\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss", :status=>"\n                    Report of Stoke's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 17", :team_name=>"Aston Villa", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"4", :home_drawn=>"5", :home_lost=>"8", :home_for=>"16", :home_against=>"25", :away_won=>"4", :away_drawn=>"5", :away_lost=>"7", :away_for=>"20", :away_against=>"35", :goal_difference=>"-24", :points=>"34", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Loss\nDraw\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Aston Villa's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 18", :team_name=>"Wigan", :played=>"32", :home_won=>"4", :home_drawn=>"4", :home_lost=>"8", :home_for=>"20", :home_against=>"32", :away_won=>"4", :away_drawn=>"3", :away_lost=>"9", :away_for=>"17", :away_against=>"26", :goal_difference=>"-21", :points=>"31", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Loss\nDraw\nDraw\nLoss\nWin\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nDraw\nLoss", :status=>"\n                    Report of Wigan's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 19", :team_name=>"QPR", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"2", :home_drawn=>"8", :home_lost=>"6", :home_for=>"12", :home_against=>"23", :away_won=>"2", :away_drawn=>"4", :away_lost=>"11", :away_for=>"17", :away_against=>"31", :goal_difference=>"-25", :points=>"24", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nDraw\nLoss\nLoss\nWin\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nDraw\nLoss", :status=>"\n                    Report of QPR's last match                "}
{:statistics=>"", :position=>"No movement 20", :team_name=>"Reading", :played=>"33", :home_won=>"4", :home_drawn=>"7", :home_lost=>"6", :home_for=>"23", :home_against=>"31", :away_won=>"1", :away_drawn=>"2", :away_lost=>"13", :away_for=>"13", :away_against=>"32", :goal_difference=>"-27", :points=>"24", :last_10_games=>"\n                                    Draw\nWin\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nLoss\nDraw", :status=>"\n                    Report of Reading's last match                "}
```

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for, so no need to grab the key then?

Comment: though i dont get the output you have shown, i get the whole hash returned for each row? so the same as when i do puts hsh

Comment: @Richlewis change `puts hsh` to `p hsh`, and see your code output. then you would get what I did. :) please test and update me

Comment: outputs the same? im guessing it worked for you?

Comment: @Richlewis did you use `p hsh`?

Comment: i tried puts hsh and p hsh

Comment: does the above work for you?

Comment: my problem is the .each, i dont get the value returned, just the whole hash..

Comment: @Richlewis I have given it as  answers, as all can't be pasted in a single place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28538/discussion-between-richlewis-and-rubylovely)

Comment: When you give code, be sure to *explain* it. As is, you gave the OP a fish. Instead, teach HOW to fish. In other words, don't do their work, show how they can do it this time, and the next, and the next....

Comment: thanks @TinMan i would rather learn that just do :)

Comment: @theTinMan can you tell what's the meaning of `'tbody tr.team'`?

Comment: It's a CSS accessor. You can figure out what it's doing by studying how those work, but a hint is to study up on jQuery, because Nokogiri implements jQuery's CSS accessors. Something else to file away is that `tbody` is *almost* never useful in CSS or XPath accessors. It's part of the spec for tables, but it's really only browsers that insert it into the rendered HTML. Us humans eschew its use.